# Ringer Mode Silent in Android Studio not working in Android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is there other way on how I could possibly do this in Android 11? I've tried this code but it's not working.

```
myAudioManager.setRingerMode(0);
```

Comment: Have you added permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Add below line in AndroidManifest.xml file. 

<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY” />

Comment: I did and I already found a way to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed it. This is what worked for me.

*silent mode*

```
audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
```

*normal mode*

```
audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
```

Comment: It mutes the RingVolume, that is true.
BUT on a Pixel5 - it makes the phone vibrate on notifications.

And conceptually Android names the volume "Ring&Notification"
so I expected the notification sound to be muted too, 
but thats not the case.